# STSを起動しようとするとエラーが出てしまいます。

Tags: java

STSを起動したら以下のようなエラーが出てしまいます。
どうしたらいいでしょうか？

> A Java Runtime Environment (JRE) or Java Development Kit (JDK) must be available in order to run STS. No Java virtual machine was found after searching the following locations: C:\STS\sts-bundle\sts-3.9.6.RELEASE\jre\bin\javaw.exe javaw.exe in your current PATH

[image: こちらがエラー画像です]

Answer (score 2):

STSを実行するにはJRE（Java）が必要です。Javaをインストールして下さい。